# How to access subdocument value when the key is a number

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo document that look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a18bdd7313101c38baa06d"),
    "date" : "2017-02-12",
    "previsions" : {
        "1000" : {
            "tmin" : "3",
            "tmax" : "13"
        },
        "1090" : {
            "tmin" : "3",
            "tmax" : "13"
        },
        "1100" : {
            "tmin" : "-1",
            "tmax" : "5"
        },
        "1110" : {
            "tmin" : "3",
            "tmax" : "12"
        },
        "1120" : {
            "tmin" : "3",
            "tmax" : "14"
        }
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-02-13T10:35:09.804Z")
}
```

and I would like to access one of tmin/tmax for one of the value, unfortunatly, since the keys are number, the mongo driver doesn't let me do so :

```
db.Temperatures.findOne().previsions.1000
```

return with the error:

```
2017-02-13T11:38:49.371+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:36
```

Is there a way to bypass this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access a key in an object that uses numeric characters, you can simply pass them as a string - objects always store their keys as strings.

```
db.Temperatures.findOne().previsions['1000']
```

That will give you this output -

```
{
  "tmin": "3",
  "tmax": "13"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MongoDB documentation

> The projection document limits the fields to return for all matching
>   documents.

Please try executing following query in MongoDB shell

```
db.Temperatures.findOne({},{'previsions.1000':1})
```